# Can any one tell me why this query is not working?

Tags: google-sheets

so I've made some queries by now, and they all have a similar format, but I can't get this one to work:

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H2fjoZx_PMuIJnxWvsIzZbhrxys_O1LKRPdabEWf5HA/edit?usp=sharin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulo,

Queries can be tricky.  Based on your dataset, you only need to make one small change to your formula for it to work.  `B = '"&B1&"'` should be changed to `B = "&B1&"` Below is a working example.

```
=QUERY(Log!A:D; "select A, B, C, D
 where A >= date '"&TEXT(E2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date '"&TEXT(F2; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"&
 IF(B1="All IDs";;" and B = "&B1&""); 1)
```

Comment: Damn, I hate these formulas some times (no I don't), thank you very much.